# Control PDF file page count in php

Tags: php

I am generating a dynamic PDF file in php. But I want to remove the first page of the PDF file from the count of pages (For an example, if there are 6 pages in the PDF file, I need to show the page count from the second page). How can I implement this? Any help please...

```
$this->Cell(207, 0, 'Proposal Report Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, 2, 'C');
```

Comment: I have edited my question (Add code for footer). Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working with the TCPDF class. In that case, you might be looking for the

`setStartingPageNumber()`

method?